# Crontab scheduling confusion

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to setup a cron job that will run a script at 30 minutes after the hour on Monday, Wednesday and Friday.

Would the command be this?

```
    sudo crontab -e        
    30 * * * 1,3,5 \path.to.script.to.be.run\scriptname
```

and if I want it to run the same script but every 30 minutes on Tuesday and Thursday, would it be:

```
    sudo crontab -e
    0,30 * * * 2,4 \path.to.script.to.be.run\scriptname
```

I don't have access to a linux system until tomorrow but want to make sure I have this right before I actually do it.

Comment: Crontab page on wikipedia might help.

Comment: What are these backslashes supposed to mean?

Comment: I accidentally did the \ instead of the /.  I am working on a Windows system right now and did a bunch of command line stuff prior to that posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct, except that you should use the forward slash character as a path separator if you're on Linux, i.e.

```
0,30 * * * 2,4 /path.to.script.to.be.run/scriptname
```

To run every 30 minutes you can also use

```
*/30 * * * 2,4 /path.to.script.to.be.run/scriptname
```

which will run at 30 and 60 minutes past the hour, or

```
5/30 * * * 2,4 /path.to.script.to.be.run/scriptname
```

which would run at 5 and 35 minutes past.